# How different is Support Vector Regression compared to SVM?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm

I know the basics about SVM and SVR, but still I don't get how the problem of finding a hyperplane which maximizes the margin fits into SVR.

Second,  I read something about $\epsilon$ used as margin of tolerance in SVR. What does it mean?

Third, is there any difference between decision function parameters used in SVM and SVR?

Comment: I made an attempt to explain it in a pictorial way using the side view https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82044/how-does-support-vector-regression-work-intuitively/351798#351798

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVM, both for classification and regression, are about optimizing a function via a cost function, however the difference lies in the cost modeling.

Consider this illustration of a support vector machine used for classification.

[image]

Since our goal is a good separation of the two classes, we try to formulate a boundary that leaves as wide a margin as possible between the instances that are closest to it (support vectors), with instances falling into this margin being a possibility, altough incurring a high cost (in the case of a soft margin SVM).

In the case of regression, the goal is to find a curve that minimizes the deviation of the points to it. With SVR, we also use a margin, but with an entirely different goal - we don't care about instances that lie within a certain margin around the curve, because the curve fits them somewhat well. This margin is defined by the parameter $\epsilon$ of the SVR. Instances that fall within the margin do not incur any cost, that's why we refer to the loss as 'epsilon-insensitive'.

[image]

For both sides of the decision function we define a slack variable each, $\xi_+, \xi_-$, to account for deviations outside of the $\epsilon$-zone.

This gives us the optimization problem (see E. Alpaydin, Introduction to Machine Learning, 2nd Edition)

$$min \frac{1}{2} ||w||^2 + C\sum_{t} (\xi_+ + \xi_-)$$

subject to

$$r^t - (\textbf{w}^T \textbf{x} + w_0) \leq \epsilon + \xi_{+}^{t}\\
 (\textbf{w}^T \textbf{x} + w_0)-r^t \leq \epsilon + \xi_{-}^{t}\\
\xi_{+}^{t},\xi_{-}^{t} \geq 0$$

Instances outside the margin of a regression SVM incur costs in the optimization, so aiming to minimize this cost as part of the optimization refines our decision function, but in fact **does not maximize the margin** as it would be the case in SVM classification.

This should have answered the first two parts of your question.

Regarding your third question: as you might have picked up by now, $\epsilon$ is an additional parameter in the case of SVR. The parameters of a regular SVM still remain, so the penalty term $C$ as well as other parameters that are required by the kernel, like $\gamma$ in case of the RBF kernel.