# What is the difference between support vector machines and support vector regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm

I understand what SVM is but I have come across people saying Support Vector Regressions (SVR) and I do not know what is the difference between SVM and SVR.

Can someone point out the **mathematical** differences between the two ? When do we use one over the other ?

Also, is there any **resources** with mathematical derivation and **R Code** which will allow me to read up on the mathematics and implementation of the Support Vector Regression?

Comment: I think this query is well addressed on the following link: [SVM vs. SVR](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Support-Vector-Machine-and-Support-Vector-Regression)

Answer (score 2):

- a support vector machine performs classification
- support vector regression performs regression

Related:

- [How does support vector regression work intuitively?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/82044/12359)
- [Support vector machines and regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13194/12359)

Comment: I think this much the OP already knows... And the linked answer is not that strong either.

Comment: @usεr11852 if he wants to know how SVR works then the question is pretty much a duplicate

Comment: I agree with your assessment this question being a potential duplicate. Maybe I read too much in the opening statement "*I understand what SVM is*" so I cannot see any non-obvious information being communicated. I will delete my comments and upvote if the OP finds this helpful (and/or accepts as an answer).

Comment: @usεr11852 I have added some answer in [Support vector machines and regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13194/12359)